# xcode iphone UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uipickerview

My UIPickerView hits the didSelectRow method without actually clicking on the item in the list.  All you have to do is flick the list to scroll and when it list stops scrolling it automatically fires this method.  How can I fix this?

Comment: That's the default behavior so you can't change it

Answer (score 0):

As herz said, this is simply how the UIPickerView behaves. You don't have to actually tap on the row to select it.

Comment: Okay well I can see how that could be nice and all but it makes things really annoying for a user.  I have a list of cities and they need to pick a city.  Is there a way to set a delay so it will delay before auto selecting the city?  Like if I scroll from A's to C's and let off my finger so I can swipe again to keep scrolling...otherwise this is a poor user experience.